# How to dynamically resize the textField based on another textField?

Tags: jasper-reports

I had this following scenario:

Textfields that form a table.

My problem is if one textField was stretched, other textField in that row should follow but not textFields in other row.

Is it possible in *iReport*?

Comment: If we are talking about increasing the height of textFields in "one row" - yes.

Comment: @AlexK how can I do that?

Comment: Try to set *stretchType*  to ***RelativeToTallestObject***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch with overflow Detail band not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293322/stretch-with-overflow-detail-band-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @AlexK Got one problem. I actually have a table and what happen is all cell have the same height. Is there something like RelativeToTallestObjectInRow or something?

Comment: RelativeToBandHeight

Comment: @DanielBristol The same situation for Table component - you should change *stretchType* for both *textFields* in cells

Comment: @PetterFriberg RelativeToBandHeight has same effect as RelativeToTallestObject since Im working on detail band only.

Comment: @AlexK I already changed stretchType for all textFields but still same problem.